# Cannot use ValuePattern even though it is supported

Tags: c#, .net, automation, ui-automation

I'm facing a problem with ValuePattern. I have the following piece of code:

```
ValuePattern valuePattern = null;

try
{
        valuePattern = AElement.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;
        valuePattern.SetValue(EditableElement.value[0].ToString());

        Debug.WriteLine(AElement.Current.Name + "'s value changed to {0}.", EditableElement.value[0].ToString());
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
        Debug.WriteLine("Value pattern not supported for " + AElement.Current.Name);
        return;
}
```

I am passing an AutomationElement with controltype.Edit and when I inspect this element, i recive this piece of info:

```
ControlType.Edit
    ValuePatternIdentifiers.Pattern
    LegacyIAccessiblePatternIdentifiers.Pattern
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in       UIAComWrapper.dll
Value pattern not supported
```

Does anyone have any idea why it says valuepattern is unsupported while ValuePatternIdentifiers.Pattern is listed in GetSupportedPatterns()?

Comment: GetSupportedPattern is just doing a loop over the list of known patterns and checks TryGetCurrentPattern for each pattern. GetCurrentPattern is itself just a wrapper on TryGetCurrentPattern. Are you sure you're calling GetSupportedPatterns and GetCurrentPattern at the same exact moment? What if you add the GetSupportedPatterns call just before the GetCurrentPattern call?

Comment: You are assuming that the InvalidOperationException is caused by the Value pattern not being supported.  It may be supported, but SetValue will throw if the control is not enabled / is readonly

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance, that the pattern disappears or becomes unavailable between the time frame between when you are checking the available patters and the moment you are triggering valuePatter.SetValue.

So, I would suggest, just print **GetAllSupportedPatterns** before you are triggering valuePattern.SetValue and verify presence of Value Pattern.

Also, you if you have a copy of UIAVerifier, you could always try doing the changes manually and isolate if there is something wrong with Window Control or Your code.